# Special character (as in España) in a php statement?

Tags: php, utf-8

Will the below statement work?
I'm worried about using España as the case query because it has a special character in it.

```
switch ($countryName) {
  case "España":
    $countryName = "Spain"
  break;
}
```

Comment: It will work, so long as the byte sequence in `$countryName` is identical.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about any of those characters. A string in PHP is just a bunch of bytes - if the bytes match your case will match.